# Update table to inserted value where current value is in deleted table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_ControlFreqKey_Update
ON ControlFreqKey
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF (UPDATE (FreqID))
BEGIN
UPDATE Controls 
Set Controls.FreqAdjustment = inserted.FreqID
FROM inserted
WHERE controls.FreqAdjustment = deleted.FreqID
```

I am trying to use a trigger as a pseudo "on update cascade" since sql server is preventing me from having two cascading paths to this table from one parent table.

How can I update the FreqAdjustment to the new FreqID where it currently equals the value it was just updated from. This code should do what I want but it won't let me use the deleted table in the where clause. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

triggers won't execute for each row when update query executes.
triggers executes once, even you update multiple rows in one update query.

so inserted and deleted are not a row, the are tables. so you must work with them like other tables.

if you are sure that just one row affected in every update in table, this will work

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_ControlFreqKey_Update
ON ControlFreqKey
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF (UPDATE (FreqID))
BEGIN
UPDATE Controls 
Set Controls.FreqAdjustment = inserted.FreqID
FROM inserted
WHERE controls.FreqAdjustment IN ( SELECT FreqID FROM deleted)
```

but i have no simple solution if you want to update multiple rows in one query.

Comment: i have no idea about it, maybe its better to write exact error message @mjcallen